# Why my signed certificate is not accepted by IOS (valid in Firefox)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, x509

I tried to generate my own CA with TLS Server Certificates. In Firefox I also do not have problems and the certificate is accepted after import of the root certificate. But after importing the root certificate to IOS and opening the site I get the message "connection not provate"

I set down the validation time, added req_cert_extensions and v3_req parts, added an intermediate CA, took attention to cipher algorithm and key length but I dont get what problem IOS has with my certificates.

THe public cert of the root is added as trusted in IOS via profiles.
Because it is not working I even added the intermediate and the cert itself as trusted profile. I also tried to add the whole chain as an IOS profile.

Here is the server certificate

```
[tsu@localhost knas]$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in 20201109_knas_crt.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            0e:bc:6e:2f:a4:b8:9d:80:1b:96:e7:45:54:2d:4d:6a:99:00:0f:7b
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = DE, ST = Saarland, O = Thomas Sulz private, OU = intermediate, CN = intermediate.wodarz.name, emailAddress = thomas@tsulz.de
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov  9 20:04:41 2020 GMT
            Not After : Sep  5 20:04:41 2021 GMT
        Subject: C = DE, ST = Saarland, L = Saarbruecken, O = Thomas Sulz private, OU = knas, CN = knas.spdns.org, emailAddress = thomas@tsulz.de
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ea:40:50:bd:f3:5f:f5:1d:66:8b:c1:01:a0:cd:
                    ...
                    ce:a0:be:8b:77:88:96:e0:0a:d1:8e:7d:58:c4:8b:
                    55:0f:b7
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Cert Type:
                SSL Server
            Netscape Comment:
                OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                CE:1D:6A:CE:4C:B5:F9:DF:ED:1B:57:EF:FF:2D:3D:8C:C2:83:B3:46
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:5C:E8:02:D9:44:27:66:20:E2:61:B6:D5:47:46:6B:15:A7:6D:70:C1
                DirName:/C=DE/ST=Saarland/L=Saarbruecken/O=Thomas Sulz private/OU=root/CN=root.thsulz.de/emailAddress=thomas@tsulz.de
                serial:01

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:knas.spdns.org, DNS:tsulz81.synology.me, IP Address:192.168.1.20, IP Address:192.168.1.21
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         0e:c4:ba:de:22:1c:4a:13:e7:5c:7f:f2:4b:d1:ff:63:41:7f:
         ...
         3e:ac:a0:4f:61:7b:b5:2d
```

here the intermediate certificate:

```
[tsu@localhost intermediate]$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in 20201109_tsulz_intermediate_crt.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = DE, ST = Saarland, L = Saarbruecken, O = Thomas Sulz private, OU = root, CN = root.tsulz.de, emailAddress = thomas@tsulz.de
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov  9 19:30:32 2020 GMT
            Not After : Nov  7 19:30:32 2030 GMT
        Subject: C = DE, ST = Saarland, O = Thomas Sulz private, OU = intermediate, CN = intermediate.tsulz.de, emailAddress = thomas@tsulz.de
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d7:20:3b:a5:06:df:16:ce:8f:d7:a9:b6:07:5a:

                    83:36:3d:87:74:30:b7:80:1e:b1:46:4f:08:cf:c8:
                    09:30:fd
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                5C:E8:02:D9:44:27:66:20:E2:61:B6:D5:47:46:6B:15:A7:6D:70:C1
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:5E:DE:69:96:9A:33:AC:3D:13:55:4E:FD:5B:AD:30:A8:7D:06:94:94

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         05:58:75:ce:40:6f:86:37:de:e1:b7:f1:5d:2d:17:82:c7:e8:
         
         1a:8e:52:01:6c:b5:91:c7
```

Comment: Can you also paste the root certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now.
I had 3 approaches and this question was the result of my thirth approach.

Finally I imported the root certificate as IOS profile but I forgot to give trust to it. To do so, I needed to got to settings-> General -> info -> Certificate trust settings (last one) and there I had to enable my root certificate.